# How do I draw a shadow under a UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I'm trying to draw a shadow under the bottom edge of a `UIView` in Cocoa Touch. I understand that I should use `CGContextSetShadow()` to draw the shadow, but the Quartz 2D programming guide is a little vague:

1. Save the graphics state.
2. Call the function `CGContextSetShadow`, passing the appropriate values.
3. Perform all the drawing to which you want to apply shadows.
4. Restore the graphics state

I've tried the following in a `UIView` subclass:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(currentContext);
    CGContextSetShadow(currentContext, CGSizeMake(-15, 20), 5);
    CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);
    [super drawRect: rect];
}
```

..but this doesn't work for me and I'm a bit stuck about (a) where to go next and (b) if there's anything I need to do to my `UIView` to make this work?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

In your current code, you save the `GState` of the current context, configure it to draw a shadow .. and the restore it to what it was before you configured it to draw a shadow. Then, finally, you invoke the superclass's implementation of `drawRect`: .

Any drawing that should be affected by the shadow setting needs to happen *after*

```
CGContextSetShadow(currentContext, CGSizeMake(-15, 20), 5);
```

but *before*

```
CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);
```

So if you want the superclass's `drawRect:` to be 'wrapped' in a shadow, then how about if you rearrange your code like this?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(currentContext);
    CGContextSetShadow(currentContext, CGSizeMake(-15, 20), 5);
    [super drawRect: rect];
    CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);
}
```

Answer (score 788):

A by far easier approach is to set some layer attributes of the view on initialization:

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-15, 20);
self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

You need to import QuartzCore.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: But be aware that this only works on iOS 3.2+ so if your app should work on old version you have to use Christian's solution or an static image behind the view if this is an option.

Comment: This solution also requires adding `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>"` to the .h file.

Comment: Setting `masksToBounds` to `NO` will negate the `cornerRadius`, no?

Comment: Okay, to solve that, the backgroundColor needs to be set on the layer and the view needs to be transparent.

Comment: @pixelfreak How do you do that? I tried `self.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];` but no luck.  Which view needs to be transparent?

Comment: @pixelfreak oh I was trying to do this to round out a UIButton with an image on it and place a drop shadow.  Looks like the UIImage overlays the rounded corner when it's not masked. Oh well, I might ask another questions.

Comment: @MusiGenesis I'm aware this is an old comment, but which line requires `QuartzCore` specifically, I've just got (what I think is the desired end result) without including it, unless it's a change in iOS 7 of course.

Comment: @JamieTaylor: referencing `self.layer` used to require the QuartzCore include.

Comment: Is there a way to keep cornerRadius? I need a shadow and rounded corners at the same time.

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans you can add corner radius on parent view and add another view with shadow as subview.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! The direction of the shadow can be changed by changing the size of the offset. For example, to create a thin shadow on the bottom, I used `CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)`.

Answer (score 234):

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.layer.cornerRadius = 8; // if you like rounded corners
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-15, 20);
self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

This will slow down the application. 
Adding the following line can improve performance as long as your view is visibly rectangular:

```
self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds].CGPath;
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting this optimisation is only useful if your view is visibly rectangular.

Comment: self.layer.shadowPath... instead of what? or just adding to it

Comment: Just add that extra line in addition to the others.

Comment: Thanks for this! Can you explain why this boosts performance when using shadows?

Comment: @NathanGaskin - drawing shadows is expensive operation, so for example if your application allows other interface orientation and you start to rotate the device, without specifying explicitly the path of the shadow it has to be rendered several times during that animation which will, depending on the shape, probably visibly slow down the animation

Comment: @BenjaminDobell That particular line only works for rectangles but you can also create non-rectangular paths.  For example, if you have a rounded rectangle you can use bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cornerRadius:

Comment: With this solution shadow is stretched from the center to the corners, but how do I stretch shadow from the upper bound of an UIView to lower bound? Thanks

Comment: @Dio its working nice with fast and not make app freeze but thare is one issue when i change the orientation UIBezierPath shadow not working properly . so give me any suggetion how to manage it with orientaion ?

Comment: The corner radius is not applied to my view. I thought masking the bounds is the only way to show these corners, but annoyingly it then removes the shadow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 162):

Same solution, but just to remind you: You can define the shadow directly in the storyboard.

Ex:

[image]

Comment: How do you set the color?
layer.shadowColor, with type Color does not cut it as the color must be of type CGColor.

Comment: Sadly, I think CGColor is out of reach from the storyboard :(

Comment: just define a category for `UIView` or `CGLayer` which is an `UIColor` wrapper for the `CGColor` property ;)

Comment: This link describes how to do so: http://cocoadventures.org/post/104137872754/how-to-add-a-shadow-on-a-view-in-interface-builder

Comment: This is awesome. I may start using this little runtime attributes panel for a lot of things I'm defining in code at runtime! +1

Comment: To make it on easier for people to copy and paste: layer.masksToBound, layer.shadowOffset, layer.shadowRadius, layer.shadowOpacity. Typos will kill you here.

Comment: layer.shadowOpacity value should be 0.5 not 0,5

Comment: @DesertRose you should type in US format but it is displayed according to your computer localisation setting.

Comment: You should never do this FYI. Don't add random KVO attributes in the storyboard.

Comment: it's `masksToBounds` with `s` and Defaults to `NO` so it's redundant, still gj

Comment: you may add shadowUIColor instead of  shadowColor

Answer (score 45):

You can try this .... you can play with the values.
The `shadowRadius` dictates the amount of blur. `shadowOffset` dictates where the shadow goes.

> Swift 2.0

```
let radius: CGFloat = demoView.frame.width / 2.0 //change it to .height if you need spread for height
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2.1 * radius, height: demoView.frame.height))
//Change 2.1 to amount of spread you need and for height replace the code for height

demoView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
demoView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
demoView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.4)  //Here you control x and y
demoView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
demoView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0 //Here your control your blur
demoView.layer.masksToBounds =  false
demoView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath
```

> Swift 3.0

```
let radius: CGFloat = demoView.frame.width / 2.0 //change it to .height if you need spread for height 
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2.1 * radius, height: demoView.frame.height)) 
//Change 2.1 to amount of spread you need and for height replace the code for height

demoView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
demoView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
demoView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.4)  //Here you control x and y
demoView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
demoView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0 //Here your control your blur
demoView.layer.masksToBounds =  false
demoView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
```

> Example with spread

[image: Example with spread]

> To create a basic shadow

```
    demoView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    demoView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    demoView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.5, 4.0); //Here your control your spread
    demoView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5 
    demoView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0 //Here your control your blur
```

> Basic Shadow example in Swift 2.0

[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 19):

*Simple and clean solution using Interface Builder*

Add a file named UIView.swift in your project (or just paste this in any file) :

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable extension UIView {

    /* The color of the shadow. Defaults to opaque black. Colors created
    * from patterns are currently NOT supported. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.shadowColor = newValue!.CGColor
        }
        get {
            if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                return UIColor(CGColor:color)
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    /* The opacity of the shadow. Defaults to 0. Specifying a value outside the
    * [0,1] range will give undefined results. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
    }

    /* The shadow offset. Defaults to (0, -3). Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGPoint {
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: newValue.x, height: newValue.y)
        }
        get {
            return CGPoint(x: layer.shadowOffset.width, y:layer.shadowOffset.height)
        }
    }

    /* The blur radius used to create the shadow. Defaults to 3. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Then this will be available in Interface Builder for every view in the Utilities Panel > Attributes Inspector :

[image: Utilities Panel]

You can easily set the shadow now.

Notes:
 - The shadow won't appear in IB, only at runtime.
 - As Mazen Kasser said

> To those who failed in getting this to work [...] make sure Clip Subviews (`clipsToBounds`) is not enabled

Comment: This is the correct answer - configuration over code for future interfaces

Comment: This solution leads me to a non working behavior with the following warning message (one for each property) : `Failed to set (shadowColor) user defined inspected property on (UICollectionViewCell): [<UICollectionViewCell> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key shadowColor.`

Comment: I had to import `UIKit` to make it work, the basic `Foundation` import created by XCode is not enough, but compiles fine. I should have copied the whole source code. Thank you Axel for this nice solution.

Answer (score 13):

I use this as part of my utils. With this we can not only set shadow but also can get a rounded corner for any `UIView`. Also you could set what color shadow you prefer. Normally black is preferred but sometimes, when the background is non-white you might want something else. Here's what I use -

```
in utils.m
+ (void)roundedLayer:(CALayer *)viewLayer 
              radius:(float)r 
              shadow:(BOOL)s
{
    [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [viewLayer setCornerRadius:r];        
    [viewLayer setBorderColor:[RGB(180, 180, 180) CGColor]];
    [viewLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    if(s)
    {
        [viewLayer setShadowColor:[RGB(0, 0, 0) CGColor]];
        [viewLayer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
        [viewLayer setShadowOpacity:1];
        [viewLayer setShadowRadius:2.0];
    }
    return;
}
```

To use this we need to call this - `[utils roundedLayer:yourview.layer radius:5.0f shadow:YES];`

Answer (score 7):

## Swift 3

```
extension UIView {
    func installShadow() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 2
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.45
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
        layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    }
}
```

Comment: if you were going this method I would consider adding parameters so you can adjust the values so its dynamic

Comment: It isn't giving rounded corner to me, am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @NikhilManapure nothing happening, this could be because the function `installShadow()` is not invoked from `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()`

Comment: I was calling it from the overloaded `draw` method of view. Shadow is coming correctly but rounded corner doesn't.

Comment: @NikhilManapure no rounded borders, this could be because the view is an `UIStackView` which only does layout and has no view. You may have to insert a regular `UIView` as a container for everything.

Comment: @neoneye It's not a `UIStackView` :(.. but I will find and reply soon.

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to use StoryBoard and wouldnt like to keep typing in runtime attributes, you can easily create an extension to views and make them usable in storyboard.

Step 1. create extension

```
extension UIView {

@IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.shadowRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowRadius = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOpacity
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOffset
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOffset = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable var maskToBound: Bool {
    get {
        return layer.masksToBounds
    }
    set {
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue
    }
}
}
```

step 2. you can now use these attributes in storyboard[image: storyboard image]

Answer (score 4):

**Sketch Shadow Using IBDesignable and IBInspectable in Swift 4**

> **HOW TO USE IT**

[image: DEMO]

> **SKETCH AND XCODE SIDE BY SIDE**

[image: Shadow Exampl]

> **CODE**

```
@IBDesignable class ShadowView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let color = newValue {
                layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
            } else {
                layer.shadowColor = nil
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGPoint {
        get {
            return CGPoint(x: layer.shadowOffset.width, y:layer.shadowOffset.height)
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: newValue.x, height: newValue.y)
        }

     }

    @IBInspectable var shadowBlur: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue / 2.0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowSpread: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if shadowSpread == 0 {
                layer.shadowPath = nil
            } else {
                let dx = -shadowSpread
                let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: dx, dy: dx)
                layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **OUTPUT**

[image: DEMO OUTPUT]

Comment: You can improve the code removing the shadow prefixes from attributes. ShadowView's aim is clear about shadow operation. One more thing is you can add corner radius to  this class. (In today,  most shadow views involves corner radius)

Answer (score 3):

To those who failed in getting this to work (As myself!) after trying all the answers here, just make sure **Clip Subviews** is not enabled at the Attributes inspector...

Answer (score 2):

You can use my utility function created for shadow and corner radius as below:

```
- (void)addShadowWithRadius:(CGFloat)shadowRadius withShadowOpacity:(CGFloat)shadowOpacity withShadowOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffset withShadowColor:(UIColor *)shadowColor withCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius withBorderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor withBorderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth forView:(UIView *)view{

    // drop shadow
    [view.layer setShadowRadius:shadowRadius];
    [view.layer setShadowOpacity:shadowOpacity];
    [view.layer setShadowOffset:shadowOffset];
    [view.layer setShadowColor:shadowColor.CGColor];

    // border radius
    [view.layer setCornerRadius:cornerRadius];

    // border
    [view.layer setBorderColor:borderColor.CGColor];
    [view.layer setBorderWidth:borderWidth];
}
```

Hope it will help you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
self.paddingView.layer.masksToBounds = false
self.paddingView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -15, height: 10)
self.paddingView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
self.paddingView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

All Answer all well but I want to add one more point

If you encounter a problem when you have table cells, Deque a new cell there is a mismatch in shadow so in this case, you need to place your shadow code in a layoutSubviews method so that it will behave nicely in all conditions.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    [VPShadow applyShadowView:self];
}
```

or in ViewControllers for specific view place shadow code inside the following method so that it's work well

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [self.viewShadow layoutIfNeeded];
    [VPShadow applyShadowView:self.viewShadow];
}
```

I have modified my shadow implementation for new devs for more generalized form ex:

```
/*!
 @brief Add shadow to a view.

 @param layer CALayer of the view.

 */
+(void)applyShadowOnView:(CALayer *)layer OffsetX:(CGFloat)x OffsetY:(CGFloat)y blur:(CGFloat)radius opacity:(CGFloat)alpha RoundingCorners:(CGFloat)cornerRadius{
    UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:layer.bounds cornerRadius:cornerRadius];
    layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(x,y);// shadow x and y
    layer.shadowOpacity = alpha;
    layer.shadowRadius = radius;// blur effect
    layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For fellow Xamarians, the Xamarin.iOS/C# version of the answer would look like the following:

```
public override void DrawRect(CGRect area, UIViewPrintFormatter formatter)
{
    CGContext currentContext = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
    currentContext.SaveState();
    currentContext.SetShadow(new CGSize(-15, 20), 5);
    base.DrawRect(area, formatter);
    currentContext.RestoreState();                
}
```

The main difference is that you acquire an instance of `CGContext` on which you directly call the appropriate methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `Extension` to add shadow

```
extension UIView {

    func addShadow(offset: CGSize, color: UIColor, radius: CGFloat, opacity: Float)
    {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowOffset = offset
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowRadius = radius
        layer.shadowOpacity = opacity

        let backgroundCGColor = backgroundColor?.cgColor
        backgroundColor = nil
        layer.backgroundColor =  backgroundCGColor
    }
}
```

you can call it like

```
your_Custom_View.addShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 1), color: UIColor.black, radius: 2.0, opacity: 1.0)
```