# Rounded UIView with Shadow?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

So using this link:
[How do I draw a shadow under a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805872/how-do-i-draw-a-shadow-under-a-uiview)

And this link:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-transparent-uiviews-rounded.html

I came upon this implementation:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(-15.0f, 20.0f), 5.0f);

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeWidth);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.strokeColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.rectColor.CGColor);

CGRect rrect = self.bounds;

CGFloat radius = cornerRadius;
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(rrect);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(rrect);


// Make sure corner radius isn't larger than half the shorter side
if (radius > width/2.0)
    radius = width/2.0;
if (radius > height/2.0)
    radius = height/2.0;    

CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rrect);
CGFloat midx = CGRectGetMidX(rrect);
CGFloat maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rrect);
CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rrect);
CGFloat midy = CGRectGetMidY(rrect);
CGFloat maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rrect);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, minx, midy);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, miny, midx, miny, radius);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, miny, maxx, midy, radius);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, maxy, midx, maxy, radius);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, maxy, minx, midy, radius);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}
```

However when it draws, the shadow is clipped to the bounds of the view. I have tried setting self.clipsToBounds = NO however this doesn't affect the problem.

Comment: This was answered a year later on a different question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690972/why-maskstobounds-yes-prevents-calayer-shadow Trick is having 2 UIViews... (one for round cornering inside the other for shadowing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about drawing the shadow using Quartz Core instead? Something like:

```
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
view.layer.shadowRadius = 4;
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.frame cornerRadius:11].CGPath; // make sure you set that for better performance
```