# How to add a rounded rectangle shape (or Box) in iphone interface?

Tags: iphone, interface, rounded-corners

I want to add a rounded rectangle shape in iphone interface but the iphone library doesn't have that object. How do i do it?

Comment: [Search Stack Overflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225383/rounded-uiview-with-shadow)

Answer (score 3):

You create an UIView subclass, in which you

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and set its layer's `cornerRadius` property in code to a certain amount:

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
self.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

If you like you could create a property of your object, say `roundedCornerRadius`, and listen to its changes using [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html), in a code fragment similar to

```
[self addObserver: self forKeyPath:@"roundedCornerRadius" options:0 context:nil];

//implement in your UIView subclass
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object                 
         change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqual: @"roundedCornerRadius"])
               self.layer.cornerRadius = roundedCornerRadius;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create rounded rectangle image of your interest. you can add this image to different UI Controls.

Answer (score 0):

luvieere's answer worked for me.

Created a UIView subclass to hold the subviews i need to round the corners of. (I used IB).

Set that view to be the view of a UIViewController.

Overloaded viewDidLoad in the view controller to call a custom "viewDidLoad" method in the custom view.

That's where I set the corner radius for the subviews that need rounded corners.