# i don't get shadow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, quartz-graphics

Here is my code:

```
CALayer *inLayer =[CALayer layer];
inLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
inLayer.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,50, 50);
inLayer.position=CGPointMake(200, 200);
inLayer.cornerRadius=25;
inLayer.masksToBounds=YES;
inLayer.shadowColor=[UIColor blackColor ].CGColor;
inLayer.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(5,10);
inLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
inLayer.contents=(id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"Close.png"].CGImage;
inLayer.name=@"Close";
[self.view.layer addSublayer:inLayer];
```

i don't get shadow. something i miss there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't set cornerRadius AND shadow on layer that has an image view stretched to its bounds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705687/cant-set-cornerradius-and-shadow-on-layer-that-has-an-image-view-stretched-to-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove this line:

```
inLayer.masksToBounds=YES;
```

your code works fine

Answer (score 1):

The shadow is drawn outside of the layer's bounds.  You have to set `inLayer.masksToBounds = NO` to see the shadow.

Of course, that will prevent `cornerRadius` from working.

You need to use two layers: an outer layer that sets the shadow, and an inner sublayer that sets `masksToBounds = YES` and `cornerRadius = 25`.