# Why setClipsToBounds:NO disables setCornerRadius: for UItableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, calayer

I'm creating UIItableview. For the first cell I want to have a user Image with a button to allow him to change the image. (not so complicated).
Somehow I have a strange problem: When I set `setMasksToBounds:NO` the `[self.userTable.layer setCornerRadius:20.0];` is simply get disabled.
I am attaching a code with output example:

```
//Initiate UserTable
//[self.userTable setClipsToBounds:NO];//from the documentation this line is set by default
[self.userTable.layer setCornerRadius:20.0];
[self.view addSubview:self.userTable];
```

later in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I add:

```
[myCellView.contentView addSubview:photo]; //My photo is UImageview
```

[image]

If I uncomment the line `[self.userTable setClipsToBounds:NO]` I get:
[image]

but my corners are not rounded any more......
I read the following questions
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690972/why-maskstobounds-yes-prevents-calayer-shadow) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705687/cant-set-cornerradius-and-shadow-on-layer-that-has-an-image-view-stretched-to-i) and still cant figure that out?
Did someone had this problem and can provide a fix which will not force me to change all my code? and also how the 2 options are related to each other?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's how `cornerRadius` works - by masking to a rounded corner. How did _you_ think it worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `setCornerRadius` applies a mask to your CALayer, which is then used to mask the bounds and create the rounded corner effect.
By calling `setMasksToBounds:NO`, you are disabling the mechanism used to round the corners.

In short, you can't have it both ways.

Consider making that row in the tableview taller, or using a custom view instead of a standard `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Tnx Nick, you are right. In the end I put a background view with round corners. I wonder why Apple documentations says clipsToBounds is default NO?(its look like the other way around).