# UIView shadow and InterfaceBuilder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, core-graphics

I want to add a drop shadow using CALayer to a UI(Image)View.
The following code works generally fine

```
previewImage.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
previewImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
previewImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
previewImage.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0f;
```

However, this only works if I create that view programmatically and add it as a subview to my main view. When that view is set up in InterfaceBuilder and defined as an IBOutlet UIImageView this does NOT work. No shadow appears.
So what am I missing here?

Comment: Quite randomly, I just found out the actual problem doesn't seem to be InterfaceBuilder, but the fact that I set my InterfaceBuilder view's clipsToBounds = YES. Having NO here is alright. So I guess then I'll have to wrap the view in a second view with clipsToBound = NO and the shadow. Is there another way?

Comment: I had the same issue, but it was because "Clip Subviews" was checked for the view in Interface Builder. Unchecking that made the CALayer shadow visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is - ensure your `UIImageView`'s `clipsToBounds` property is set to `NO`. You can do this in `viewDidLoad` after loading from the nib file by referencing your IBOutlet. You shouldn't need to wrap it in another view.


**Edit**

In light of you needing your image to be scaled using aspect fill, you can use the `contentsRect` property of the `UIImageView`'s underlying layer to 'simulate' the effect of the contents clipping. `contentsRect` is rectangle in the unit coordinate space of the layer's content (in this case your image) that defines a sub-rectangle of the contents that should be drawn.

With a little bit of maths, we can find this rectangle by comparing the image view size with the image size (accounting for the aspect fill scaling):

```
CGSize imageViewSize = previewImage.size;
CGSize imageSize = previewImage.image.size;

// Find the scaling required for the image to fit the image view (as for aspect fill).
CGFloat imageWidthScale = fabsf(imageViewSize.width / imageSize.width);
CGFloat imageHeightScale = fabsf(imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height);
CGFloat imageScale = (imageWidthScale > imageHeightScale) ? imageWidthScale : imageHeightScale;

// Determine the new image size, after scaling.
CGSize scaledImageSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(imageSize, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(imageScale, imageScale));

// Set the layer's contentsRect property in order to 'clip' the image to the image view's bounds.
previewImage.layer.contentsRect = CGRectMake(((scaledImageSize.width - imageViewSize.width) / 2.0f) / scaledImageSize.width,
                                             ((scaledImageSize.height - imageViewSize.height) / 2.0f) / scaledImageSize.height,
                                             imageViewSize.width / scaledImageSize.width,
                                             imageViewSize.height / scaledImageSize.height);
```

Doing this, you can leave `clipsToBounds` set to `NO` for your image view, but the image will still appear clipped. If you need to change the image view size at all, it might be convenient to wrap this code up into a method that takes a `UIImageView` as a parameter.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I agree. No wrapping necessary. Just don't clipToBounds - as the shadow is outside of the bounds.

Comment: The reason I need clipToBounds is, that image is too big to fit the view and I need to use "Aspect Fill" to make it look good. I could, of course, crop the image itself by drawing it entirely new and then getting a fitting one through UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(). But wouldn't that be a lot overhead?

Comment: @Dennis: If the image is static and will only ever be used at that size, then my first suggestion would be to recreate the image in your image editing software first, and then use it in your project's image view without the need to alter its geometry. If this is not an option, however, then see my edit above.

Answer (score 26):

Add a file named UIView.swift in your project (or just paste this in any file) :

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable extension UIView {

    /* The color of the shadow. Defaults to opaque black. Colors created
    * from patterns are currently NOT supported. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.shadowColor = newValue!.CGColor
        }
        get {
            if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                return UIColor(CGColor:color)
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    /* The opacity of the shadow. Defaults to 0. Specifying a value outside the
    * [0,1] range will give undefined results. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
    }

    /* The shadow offset. Defaults to (0, -3). Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGPoint {
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: newValue.x, height: newValue.y)
        }
        get {
            return CGPoint(x: layer.shadowOffset.width, y:layer.shadowOffset.height)
        }
    }

    /* The blur radius used to create the shadow. Defaults to 3. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Then this will be available in Interface Builder for every view in the Utilities Panel > Attributes Inspector :

[image: Utilities Panel]

You can easily set the shadow now.

Notes:
 - The shadow will only appear at runtime.
 - `clipsToBounds` should be false (by default it is)

Comment: shadowColor will conflict with UILabel https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620536-shadowcolor

Answer (score 17):

I know this question has long, but recently i was in a similar situation so i decided to put my answer for those who are in a situation like this.

I wanted to be able to set the `borderColor` and `shadowColor` on an `UIView` through the Interface Builder, but the type of a layer’s `borderColor` property is `CGColor` (just like `shadowColor`) which is not one of the types allowed to be changed in the user-defined runtime attributes feature.

So i made an extension for `CALayer`and i added two properties called borderColorIB and shadowColorIB that are of type UIColor:

RuntimeAttributes.h

```
@import QuartzCore;

@interface CALayer (IBConfiguration)

@property(nonatomic, assign) UIColor* borderColorIB;
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIColor* shadowColorIB;

@end
```

RuntimeAttributes.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RuntimeAttributes.h"

@implementation CALayer (IBConfiguration)

-(void)setBorderColorIB:(UIColor*)color
{
    self.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}

-(UIColor*)borderColorIB
{
    return [UIColor colorWithCGColor:self.borderColor];
}

-(void)setShadowColorIB:(UIColor*)color
{
    self.shadowColor = color.CGColor;
}

-(UIColor*)shadowColorIB
{
    return [UIColor colorWithCGColor:self.shadowColor];
}

@end
```

Now i alredy be able to set this two properties through Interface Builder like this:

1. In the 'user-defined runtime attributes' section (Identity inspector)
2. Make sure the UIView is selected, and add the following runtime attributes:

   - layer.borderWidth, Number, 1
   - layer.borderColorIB, Color, someColor `<- my custom property to set the borderColor`
   - layer.shadowColorIB, Color, someColor `<- my custom property to set the shadowColor`
   - layer.shadowOpacity, Number, 0.8
   - layer.shadowOffset, size, {5,5}
   - layer.cornerRadius, Number, 5

Here is an image to show you how i did:

[image]

... and The result will be apparent during runtime, not in Xcode:

[image]

i hope this can help some people out there!

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5 Xcode 11.3.1 version of mauricioconde's answer. Note that without @IBInspectable it wouldn't work.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

extension CALayer {

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowUIColor: UIColor? {
        get { shadowColor != nil ? UIColor(cgColor: shadowColor!) : nil }
        set { shadowColor = newValue?.cgColor }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

UIView shadow with corner radius + interface builder - swift4

```
    extension UIView {

        @IBInspectable
        var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
            get {
                return layer.cornerRadius
            }
            set {
                layer.cornerRadius = newValue
                if shadowOpacity > 0.0 {
                    layer.masksToBounds = false
                }
                else {
                    layer.masksToBounds = true
                }
            }
        }
      @IBInspectable
        var borderWidth: CGFloat {
            get {
                return layer.borderWidth
            }
            set {
                layer.borderWidth = newValue
            }
        }
    @IBInspectable
        var borderColor: UIColor? {
            get {
                if let color = layer.borderColor {
                    return UIColor(cgColor: color)
                }
                return nil
            }
            set {
                if let color = newValue {
                    layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
                } else {
                    layer.borderColor = nil
                }
            }
      @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
            set {
                layer.shadowColor = newValue!.cgColor
            }
            get {
                if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                    return UIColor(cgColor: color)
                }
                else {
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
       @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
            set {
                layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
            }
            get {
                return layer.shadowOpacity
            }
        }
     @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGPoint {
            set {
                layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: newValue.x, height: newValue.y)
            }
            get {
                return CGPoint(x: layer.shadowOffset.width, y:layer.shadowOffset.height)
            }
        }
     @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
            set {
                layer.shadowRadius = newValue
            }
            get {
                return layer.shadowRadius
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: shadowColor will conflict with UILabel https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620536-shadowcolor