# shadowOffset + CornerRadius TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I'm trying to put shadow and corner radius to a tableView. The `cornerRadius` works fine but the `shadowOffset` doesn't work:

```
CGRect shadowFrame = self.mainTableView.layer.bounds;
CGPathRef shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowFrame].CGPath;
self.mainTableView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath;
self.mainTableView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.mainTableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
self.mainTableView.layer.shadowOpacity = 4.0;
self.mainTableView.layer.shadowRadius = 7.0;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of the layout of your views?

Comment: Do you use IB? If yes, try it via IB.

Comment: @Darwin You cannot set shadow paths nor corner radii through IB...

Comment: @Wayne You can with shadow offset. But obviously not with an UITableView. You are right.

Comment: @Darwin That is only because some subclasses of `UIView` expose their own shadow properties. `CALayer` properties cannot be set in IB.

Comment: Please elaborate on what "doesn't work" means. What are you expecting to see, and what are you actually seeing? Also, your `shadowPath` should probably have the corner radii baked in.

Comment: i guess... that im expecting to see a shadow using the shadowOffset...

Comment: @WayneHartman heres and screenshot http://imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&l=img46/9516/capturadepantalla201201u.png&via=mupload&newlp=1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried that ?

```
self.mainTableView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically for this to be achieved you need to use two views.

See this link: [Why masksToBounds = YES prevents CALayer shadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690972/why-maskstobounds-yes-prevents-calayer-shadow)