# UIView shadow not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

This is my code.

```
listView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
listView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-3, 3);
listView.layer.shadowColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
listView.layer.shadowRadius = 4;
listView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
[listView.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
```

It works good with shadow effect.

While changing

```
listView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

I didnt get shadow effect.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The shadow is actually drawn below the UIView.  If you set maskToBounds to YES, this clips any drawing outside of the UIView frame.  [Here is a SO link that describes this in more detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690972/why-maskstobounds-yes-prevents-calayer-shadow)

Answer (score 24):

The shadow is drawn outside of the layer's bounds. You have to set `listView.layer.masksToBounds = NO` to see the shadow

if you set `listView.layer.masksToBounds = YES` you can't draw anything out side of bounds so you can not get shadow

Comment: this was most helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Only below worked for me

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:subView];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use `masksToBounds = YES;` check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437750/uiview-round-corners-with-shadow). It tells you how to use both shadows and rounded corners (in this particular case) on a view by using two nested views: the outer view casts the shadow and does not mask to bounds while the inner view has rounded corners and masks to bounds.