# Create shadow using QuartzCore for UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, shadow, quartz-core

I have created a shadow using `QuartzCore` for my `UITextView` with this following code.

```
myTextView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
myTextView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
myTextView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
myTextView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f);
myTextView.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0f;
myTextView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

It creates a `shadow` and `looks good too.` Here it is my output for the above code.

[image]

But When I try to add a text to the `myTextView`, my textView text goes out of the bounds and it looks outside of the `myTextView` like below.

[image]

**It's happening only when I add shadow**. The text inside the `textView` is not showing weird If I don't add shadow.What I am doing wrong?? How could I overcome this? Why it is happening?

**UPDATE:**

`@borrrden` said
I found It is happening, because of setting the `maskToBounds = NO;` If we set `YES` then we cannot get shadow. Reason Here it is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690972/why-maskstobounds-yes-prevents-calayer-shadow)

Comment: `masksToBounds` is set to `NO`.  Without this, the view will not attempt to clip its content.

Comment: If I set **myTextView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;** then it's not showing any shadow.

Comment: Try setting `textView.contentInset` to an appropriate value so that it wont overlap there.

Comment: @ACB No. I think it's not anything to do with contentInset. Content Inset is only to make some space on all the sides. Anyway I tried as you said and it doesn't changed anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "right" solution, because of UIView behavior. When masksToBounds is NO, any sublayers that extend outside the layer's boundaries will be visible. And UITextField scroll text outside the UITextField layer.

Add clear view behind the UITextView and drop a shadow on it.

Comment: What do you mean by clear View? What If I have another superview behind the textView??

Comment: I think what he meant is to add a separate UIVIew as a container view behind the textview and give shadow effect to that. If you are using this textview in multiple places, probably you can subclass a UIVIew and add textview as subview in the custom implementation. +1 for the suggestion.

Comment: @ACB But Actually I am trying to add a shadow for my textview. But you are giving alternate solution. I already know to add a UIView behind to textView to make a look like what i wanted. Anyway its answer my question **how could I overcome this?**. But why I am getting like my output? What If I want to add shadow only to textView? What If I have large number of textViews?? Then I need to create large number of UIViews unwantedly and making outlets for them too...

Comment: +1 for suggestion to have an alternate way..

Comment: @R.A There is no "right" solution, because of UIView behavior. When masksToBounds is NO, any sublayers that extend outside the layer's boundaries will be visible. And UITextField scroll text outside the UITextField layer.

Comment: This is a horrible truth.

Answer (score 2):

Just add another UIView under your textView and set it's layer to display shadow (do not forget to set it's background color to something other than clear color - or shadow wont be drawn)

```
myTextView = [UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,200,200);
UIView* shadowView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myTextView.frame];
shadowView.backgroundColor = myTextView.backgroundColor;
shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
shadowView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f);
shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0f;
shadowView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
[someView addSubview:shadowView];
[someView addSubView:myTextView];
```

Comment: I need to add a shadow to textView not to the container Views. **Could you help me with my output, why it is happening when I add shadow to my textView??**

Comment: +1 for suggestion to have an alternate way..

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer, just copy all attributes from the original uiTextView to the helper view:

```
UITextView *helperTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
helperTextView = textView;  //copy all attributes to the helperTextView;

shadowTextView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:textView.frame];
shadowTextView.backgroundColor = textView.backgroundColor;
shadowTextView.layer.opacity = 1.0f;
shadowTextView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
shadowTextView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColorFromRGB(0x00abff)CGColor];
shadowTextView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
shadowTextView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
shadowTextView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
shadowTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
shadowTextView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

[self.view addSubview:shadowTextView];
[self.view addSubview:helperTextView];
```