# How to create innerShadow in textField iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios7, textfield, xcode5

since iOS 7 my textField will not get "shadowed" as it did in earlier versions of iOS automatically. I would like to add an innerShadow in the textfield. Which is the best approach to do so since iOS 7 ? The code below is how i code my textField. You can see the difference between iOS 7 and iOS 6 here: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ufewx0&s=5#.Uksu6hbU-8V

```
 UITextField* sbTextField;

    //[sbTextField removeFromSuperview];
    for (UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subviews){
        for (UIView *ndLeveSubView in subView.subviews){

            if ([ndLeveSubView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                sbTextField = (UITextField *)ndLeveSubView;

                sbTextField.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor];

                self.navigationItem.titleView = sbTextField;
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  menuButton;
                // [sbTextField removeFromSuperview];

                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506667/create-shadow-using-quartzcore-for-uitextview) and make the radius negative (I'm just guessing). Also if its inside a superview thats animated (such as a tableview) this can cause rendering problems and make it very slow.