# UITextfield background drop shadow

Tags: ios

Anyone know how to add a background drop view to a UITextfield?  I have tried this code, but this adds a shadow to the text not the UITextfield view.

```
self.txtFirstName.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
self.txtFirstName.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
self.txtFirstName.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.txtFirstName.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);
```

Comment: Don't set your textfield background color to clear color

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506667/create-shadow-using-quartzcore-for-uitextview) answer.