# How to set corner radius for TableView cells in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi i am new for iOS and in my app i am using TableList and i want to set the tableList cell corner radius as 3.0. Here is my code. It is only applying the corner radius on left corner instead of all corners.

### my code:-

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 75;
}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MyCell";

        Cell = (MyTripsCell *)[MaintableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (Cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTripsCell" owner:self options:nil];
            Cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        Cell.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
        Cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return Cell;
    }


    -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [Bg colorWithHexString:@"EEEEEE"];
        UIView * whiteRoundedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 12, MaintableView.frame.size.width, 70)];

        whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = [Bg colorWithHexString:@"FDFDFD"].CGColor;

        whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, -1);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedView];
        [cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedView];

        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
            [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }
        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
            [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
        }
        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
            [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: no i am not using autolayout

Comment: both left corner you getting the radius? top or bottom?

Comment: call your function in cellforrowat indexpath, it suely works

Comment: all side i want to set corner radius

Comment: No no i am telling you currently you getting on left side top or leftside bottom?

Comment: left side i am getting

Comment: leftside top corner ?

Comment: no sorry at right only it's applying

Comment: UIView * whiteRoundedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds]; have you try this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105098/discussion-between-abhiram-and-jogshardik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

The code is okay as it doing the corner radius at every corner but the problem is that you are actually moving the origin of the view to **y=12**. The view has the same width as the tableView, and it has the corner radius you are just not seeing this as the view goes out of screen on the right side.

### Solution

In order to have your view in the middle of the screen you set its center to the contentView's center. And work with the width to set padding.

Your code solution:

```
// Using this width and setting the view to the center will give you padding of 12 pixels on left and right
NSInteger width = MaintableView.frame.size.width - 24;
UIView * whiteRoundedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 70)];
whiteRoundedView.center = cell.contentView.center;

whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = [Bg colorWithHexString:@"FDFDFD"].CGColor;

whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, -1);
[cell.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedView];
[cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedView];

if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
}
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

Anyway I can provide some improvement to that code by not adding that view everytime that the cell is being dequeued. Also note that setting `maskToBounds = YES` for this view, will cause your shadow to not be shown (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690972/why-maskstobounds-yes-prevents-calayer-shadow))

### My Code Solution (Edited)

```
UIView *roundedView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
if (roundedView == nil) {
    // Add some padding to the view in order to see the shadow
    NSInteger spacingBothHorizontal = 2;
    CGRect customizedFrame = CGRectMake(spacingBothHorizontal/2, 0, CGRectGetWidth(cell.contentView.frame) - spacingBothHorizontal, CGRectGetHeight(cell.contentView.frame) - 20);
    roundedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:customizedFrame];
    
    // Layer customizations
    roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    roundedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    roundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, -1);
    roundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 2.0;
    roundedView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    roundedView.tag = 100;
    
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    
    // Add it to view
    [cell.contentView addSubview:roundedView];
    [cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:roundedView];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: hi i want to apply color for cells space

Comment: You can add a view for that which will reside on the bottom of each cell. And you can set the center of the roundedView only horizontally and vertically at origin, so it will create the idea of a cell space

Comment: i am very new for this technology please provide some code for those

Comment: @AbhiRam I edited the answer to match your requirements, but since you are new here, I did it for you, but you must try something out yourself and ask another question if you don't succeed. Hope this helps, and you can upvote and accept it.

Comment: ok but except cell remaining all color must be black but ur screen not seemms like that and i hope u understand

Comment: except cell remaining every empty space color must be black please  do like that then everything fine

Comment: Then you just set the contentView background color and remove spaceView

Comment: no not working if u don't mind may i send my sample project file,it just small one

Comment: really there is small problem is coming in my app with update ur code

Comment: please just see https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05NQoG9RAmwaHhweVYxbXNEbk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: in ViewController5 ur code i updated please see once and i ma not understand why problem is coming

Comment: Yeah because you have very much different things there, which are totally another matter. Check the implementation file [here](https://codeshare.io/woj4l)

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason can be:

Your cell height is 75. and you are writing this:

```
UIView * whiteRoundedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 12, MaintableView.frame.size.width, 70)];
```

See the actual `CGRectMake`

```
CGRect CGRectMake ( CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height );
```

In your case y = 12. It's superview's according to cell's coordinate its `(0,0,width,height)` when you put a subview (your `whiteRoundedView` ) that is (0, 12, width, height) its lower portion will not be displayed. As its out of cells viewport. Try to understand these coordinate system.

**EDIT:**

Change your view code to this:

```
UIView * whiteRoundedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 3, cell.frame.size.width, 69)];
```

and set corner radius to 10.

```
whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
```

Run the app and see the difference.

Comment: waht is solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code.
Is this you are looking for?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }
    if ([cell viewWithTag:100] == nil)
    {
        UIView* roundedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 2, 2)];
        roundedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        roundedView.tag = 100;
        roundedView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell insertSubview:roundedView atIndex:0];
        roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        roundedView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

In your case, use following and remove willdisplaycell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    if ([cell viewWithTag:100] == nil)
    {
        UIView* roundedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 2, 2)];
        roundedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        roundedView.tag = 100;
        roundedView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell insertSubview:roundedView atIndex:0];
        roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        roundedView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello world";

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 75;
}
```

Comment: what about willdisplay delegate method?

Comment: Why do you need that method?. try this sample code in separate project and see id this is what you are looking for. I dont think willdisplay method is required here.

Comment: this is my sample project here i want to set space b/w each cell and want to set corner radius please see this once

Comment: u see my project file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105099/discussion-between-abhiram-and-amit-tandel).