# iPhone subview with shadow

Tags: ios, shadow, subview

I have added a subview onto my main view and wish it to have a small shadow, feathered.

Is there a way?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805872/how-do-i-draw-a-shadow-under-a-uiview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another view offest by shadow size