# How can I draw a shadow beyond a UIView's bounds?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

I'm using the method described at [How do I draw a shadow under a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805872/how-do-i-draw-a-shadow-under-a-uiview) to draw shadow behind a view's content. The shadow is clipped to the view's bounds, although I disabled "Clip Subviews" in Interface Builder for the view. Is it possible to draw a shadow *around* a view and not only *in* a view?

I don't want to draw the shadow inside the view because the view would receive touch events for the shadow area, which really belongs to the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not encouraged to draw outside view bounds. Maybe you can include the shadow directly in your background...

Regards,

Comment: Why is it not encouraged to draw outside view bounds? In case of shadows, specifically, any reasons?

Comment: it cause performance issue, because of blending colors between two layers, background layer and shadow layer, its cpu intensive. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794256/1348121

Answer (score 6):

Instead of manual drawing in drawRect, consider setting properties on the the UIView's Core Animation layer for drawing a shadow.

For example:

```
[descriptionInput setClipsToBounds:NO];
[descriptionInput.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[descriptionInput.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
[descriptionInput.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0, 3.0)];
```

For this to work, you need to include QuartzCore:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

[clipsToBounds](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW60) only controls the clipping for children of a view, not drawing of that view itself; hence it's not solving your problem.

If you can draw your shadow onto a different view and add that as a child, it won't get clipped. However, I don't know how possible that is with the method you're using :(