# UIView shadow drawing wrong

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview, shadow

Trying to draw a shadow using code from this question: [How do I draw a shadow under a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805872/how-do-i-draw-a-shadow-under-a-uiview)

I implement it in a UIView subclass as discussed, but when I try and use it using `UIView *shadow = [[ShadowView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];` I get only a black square, rather than something resembling shadow.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I get the same issue with the black square.

Answer (score 1):

I know this an ancient question, but I came across it via google as I was trying to do the same thing. So I thought I would post incase anyone else has the same problem. I finally discovered a fix after reading this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2134/core-graphics-101-glossy-buttons

You need to either uncheck **Opaque**, and set the Background to **Clear Color** in IB.

OR as shown in the tutorial set them in initWithCoder

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you probably need to explicitly add an #import  to the top of your class.  I've had the same issue before and that fixed it. (Can't exactly explain why though)

Comment: That can't be it.  If I didn't have the import the compiler would throw an error at me.  Regardless, I have #import "ShadowView.h" in my header.