# UIView create a inner shadow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios5, uiview

I would like to obtain a `UIView` like this :

[image: Screenshot]

But i don't know, what is the best way to do this ?

Is this the best way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9214570/1228634 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the shadow as a transparent layer at a particular size, also create a stretchable image, like this:

```
UIImage *shadowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shadow.png"];
shadowImage = [shadowImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:floorf(shadowImage.size.width/2) topCapHeight:floorf(shadowImage.size.height/2)];
```

Put the image in a UIImageView with contentMode as scale to fit.

Call your view as "sView". You can add the shadow like this:

```
UIImageView *shadowImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:shadowImage];
shadowImgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
shadowImgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
shadowImgView.frame = sView.bounds;
[sView shadowImgView];
[shadowImgView release]; // only needed if you aren't using ARC
```

Comment: Thanks but are you a example of shadow.png ?

Comment: This worked for me.You can try the answer of samvermette here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231690/inner-shadow-in-uilabel

Comment: I just happen to have a shadow top and left but not bottom and right o_O

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use several pictures (as it works for html), but I don't think it is better than your example:

- you need 4 small pictures to make a texture for top, left, right and bottom border
- you need 4 pictures for your View's corners;
- draw to make a border from first 4 images using repeating;
- draw corner images.