# UICollectionView Cell Shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, calayer

I am trying to add shadow to my custom `UICollectionViewCell`, This is the code I am using in my custom collection view cell class:

```
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 0);
self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = .25;
```

This is giving shadow to the components of the collection view cell.

Comment: Could you please explain what `self` is in this context?

Comment: self is the custom uicollectionview cell class

Comment: Try adding the shadow to the cell's `contentView`

Comment: Please check if you have a UIView on top of your Cell. In such case, you need to mask it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shadow not showing when background color is clear color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927626/shadow-not-showing-when-background-color-is-clear-color)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14660782/294949

Answer (score 18):

**Don't forget to add these 2 lines**

```
self.clipsToBounds = false      
self.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Comment: Great, spent hours searching how to fix! Thanks!)

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4.2 and xcode 10

here's code for adding a shadow.

```
    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)//CGSizeMake(0, 2.0);
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:cell.bounds, cornerRadius:cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
```

Answer (score 4):

cell.layer.backgroundColor should not be clear color

try

```
cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to  CustomCollectionViewCell.m file
Worked for me. Hope it helps...

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        //////// make shadow  of total view
        self.clipsToBounds = NO;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
        self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds].CGPath;

        // make radius of the cell
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

    }
    return self;
}
```