# UIBezierPath around UIImage with Transparency

Tags: ios, uiimage, uibezierpath

I have a series of images that are centered on top of a transparent background. I would like to add a white border to all of them and I could draw it if I had the path of the border of the opaque part of the image. Is it possible to extract this?

Comment: You can accomplish the same thing by adding a shadow to the layer. [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5428108/2487322)

Comment: Are the images in `UIImageView`s?  If so, a much easier way to add borders is to use layers.  E.g., `myImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor` and `myImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.f`  You will need to add the QuartzCore framework to your target, and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in the .m files using the layers.

Comment: I don't want a square shadow or border, I want it to be the same shape of the image it contains.