# View Shadow in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics

I have achieved a view that looks like this —

[image]

But I want the bottom of the view to look like this —

[image]

Adding a shadow is not helping because as soon as I do `maskToBounds = YES`, I get what I have in the first picture. This is the code I have so far

```
[self.contentView.layer setCornerRadius:3.0f];
UIColor* color = CardBorderColor; // this is a macro that defines the color
[self.contentView.layer setBorderColor:color.CGColor];
[self.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[self.contentView.layer setShadowColor:color.CGColor];
[self.contentView.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
[self.contentView.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
[self.contentView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];
self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIView with rounded corners and drop shadow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754392/uiview-with-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadow)

Comment: Try this code.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805872/how-do-i-draw-a-shadow-under-a-uiview

Comment: Wow, I don't know why someone voted this down. Totally legit question.  (I voted +1 to bring it up to 0.) Do you absolutely need masksToBounds = YES? If you need it for another element, then try putting the view that requires masksToBounds within another view and adding the shadow to the bottom view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, yes, using `masksToBounds` will mask out your shadow. If you need to set `maskToBounds = YES` for another element in that view, then put the view that requires masksToBounds on top of another `UIView` and adding the shadow to that bottom view.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing — Added a parent view of the shadow colour, and made the current view 3 pixels smaller and added to that parent view. It looks the way I wanted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial link may help you..

http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-10-adding-a-shadow-to-uiview/

[How do I draw a shadow under a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805872/how-do-i-draw-a-shadow-under-a-uiview)