# How do a set an opaque 1px high shadow image for a UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

In my application delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function, I try to customize the appearance of my navigation bar.

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = NO;
[[UINavigationBar appearance] 
    setBackgroundImage:[UIImage 
        imageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] 
        size:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)
    ] 
    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault
];
[UINavigationBar appearance].shadowImage = [UIImage 
    imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor] 
    size:CGSizeMake(0.5f, 0.5f)
];
```

I expect a 1px tall opaque red shadow. Instead I am given a 2px tall translucent red shadow. How can make it appear exactly as I want it to? I've done the analogous appearance settings to UITabBar. It, on the other hand, behaves nicely.

[image]

The category function that creates dynamic images is defined as so:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: have you looked into just adding a shadow to the CALayer? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805872/how-do-i-draw-a-shadow-under-a-uiview

Comment: @cmyr `[UINavigationBar appearance].layer.borderWidth = 0.5f; [UINavigationBar appearance].layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;` shows nothing under the navigation bar.

Comment: have you set the layer's clipsToBounds to NO?

Answer (score 17):

You need to create a graphics context that is retina-aware :

```
let pixelScale = UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(fillRect.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
```

After that, your shadow image will become 1 physical pixel tall.

Here's full code:

```
extension UIImage {

    static func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let pixelScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        let pixelSize = 1 / pixelScale
        let fillSize = CGSize(width: pixelSize, height: pixelSize)
        let fillRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: fillSize)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(fillRect.size, false, pixelScale)
        let graphicsContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(graphicsContext, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(graphicsContext, fillRect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }

}
```

On GitHub:

https://github.com/salutis/swift-image-with-color

Comment: I'd propose making the fill size {1, pixelSize} instead of {pixelSize, pixelSize}, otherwise it creates a horizontal gradient effect and the line becomes transparent at the rightpoint point in my case.

Answer (score -2):

Uh...is this what you want?

[image: screenshot]

In my view controller, I simply added a UIView with 1 pixel height and an offset of 44pixels:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self setupNavBar];
}

-(void)setupNavBar
{
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Contacts";

    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    UIView *bar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, applicationFrame.size.width, 1.0)];
    bar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:bar];
}
```

You can change the color to whatever you want.

Comment: IMHO I think it's not the best solution to add a subview to a navigationBar. It seems error prone (e.g. when multiple view controllers try to add views or - esp - when the view hierarchy for navigation bars might change with an updated version of iOS). I think it's much safer to use publicly available functionalities, a custom background image and UIAppearance settings instead.