# What's the best way to add a black shadow to a UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, shadow

Lets suppose i have a simple UIView with an imageView inside of it, i want to add a black shadow at the bottom of the image, what's the best way to do it in iOS7+ ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I think they already answered this here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/806723/4489141

I hope it will work for you