# UIView shadow, cornerradius not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

```
@IBOutlet weak var selectorSemiView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var blurEffect: UIVisualEffectView!
@IBOutlet var outerAreaRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    selectorSemiView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    selectorSemiView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    selectorSemiView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    selectorSemiView.layer.shadowRadius = 7

}
```

selectorSemiView is a container view

When I run this app, there is no shadow and no rounded corner.

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

your code is fine but you forget to set the opacity, if you need the more information you can get the another answer in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805872/how-do-i-draw-a-shadow-under-a-uiview), for e.g

```
 selectorSemiView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    selectorSemiView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    selectorSemiView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero  
    selectorSemiView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    selectorSemiView.layer.shadowRadius = 7.0
    selectorSemiView.layer.masksToBounds =  false
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: When I include         selectorSemiView.clipsToBounds = true, There is rounded corner but no shadow, but when I don't include selectorSemiView.clipsToBounds = true
, there is shadow but now rounded corner

Comment: Thats because shadow is applied **outside** the bounds and `clipsToBounds` well clips out. You need to fake this behaviour by adding another view of the same size and adding shadow on to it.

Comment: why clip to bounds is not working when apply shadow by using this solution ? With my height constant when i am setting it to 0, inner content still displays.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add

```
selectorSemiView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: While a possible answer, you haven't explained why this would work.

Comment: When I set this property to true, nothing is shown at all.