# Putting box shadow on UITableView cells not showing [Swift 3]

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to put a box shadow on a table view in my iOS app. I tried different techniques for this, but have not yet managed to fix it. I've tried to add the shadow on the layer of the cell itself first :

```
cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

This didn't work, so I tried to put box shadow on the content view :

```
cell.contentview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
cell.contentview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
cell.contentview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
cell.contentview.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

I also tried to add an extra view with the same constraints in the table view cell and put the box shadow on that view, but this didn't change the result. [result with extra view and constraints and cornenradius](http://nl.tinypic.com/r/32zl1et/9)

Something special in the table view is the following :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section != 0 {
        return 10
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.tintColor = UIColor.init(netHex: 0xF9FAFD)
}
```

The table view data is all put in seperate sections, and 1 row per section.

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567288/uiview-shadow-cornerradius-not-working/43567400#43567400

Comment: I tried the solution which was explained there, but it had no effect.

Comment: can u update the question once

Comment: I updated the question now.

Answer (score 3):

According to me you should do following:

1) Wrap all UITableviewCell Views in a containerView.

2)Give margins to that parent containerView like 10px from each side.

3)Then apply

```
cell.containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
cell.containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
cell.containerView.layer.shadowOffset = //any offset
cell.containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

Note: Rasterize cell layers contents to avoid redrawing it always

```
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

Comment: How would I add the margins to the containerview? I have this code at the moment : cell.backView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            cell.backView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
            cell.backView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
            cell.backView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
            cell.backView.layer.cornerRadius = 15                                                     The result is the following : ![Result](http://nl.tinypic.com/r/6ekfaw/9).

Comment: using auto layout like leading,traling,top and bottom constraint. to 10

Comment: This is the result when I try this : [result with margin](http://nl.tinypic.com/r/xm9a8j/9) and [result in simulator](http://nl.tinypic.com/r/32zl1et/9)

Comment: Actually you need to clear all constraints and then reapply .

Comment: This did not have the result I wanted, I want the border shadow to be on the outside borders of the cell itself, now it puts a shadow on the inside of the cell.

Comment: well you can decrease the constrain to 2 so that it look as cell. itself