# How to draw shadow around the masked UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I want to make a `UIView` which will have shape like in **Figure 1**. and also should have  shadow around the shape of my view .

[image]

I am using below code to draw  `CAShaperLayer` with `UIBezierPath`

```
 UIBezierPath *bezier = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
  [bezier moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0,7)];
  [bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.menuView.frame.size.width-15, 7)];
  [bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.menuView.frame.size.width-10,0)];
  [bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.menuView.frame.size.width-5, 7)];
  [bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.menuView.frame.size.width, 7)];
  [bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.menuView.frame.size.width, self.menuView.frame.size.height)];
  [bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.menuView.frame.size.height)];
  [bezier closePath];
   
   CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
   maskLayer.path = [bezier CGPath];
   
  self.menuView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

and for adding shadow

```
self.menuView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:8.0f/255.0f green:37.0f/255.0f blue:82.0f/225.0f alpha:1] CGColor];
    self.menuView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    self.menuView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3f;
    self.menuView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
    self.menuView.layer.masksToBounds=NO;
```

**My Problem** :

After masking `CAShaperLayer` on menuView  ,the shadow has disappeared . **Figure 2**

[image]

Instead of Masking View , i also tried to add Sublayer on it

`[self.menuView.layer addSublayer:maskLayer]`

but  this will hide my all `SubViews` of MenuView **Figure 3**

*(I have changed the CASahperLayer Color to Black just to show )*

[image]

**My Question is** :

What is the best way to get the perfect shape with shadow as shown in **Figure 1**  ???.

*(Thanks in advance)*

Comment: How about a transparent view fully covered with a background imageView.  The image in that imageView can have (from the edges inward) transparent edges, the shadow, and the white body with the triangle.  If the menu has variable number of items, the image can be resizable with cap insets.

Comment: if i have to take `ImageView` that would be better to take the Trangle shape image on the top and than i'll put shadow on my View this will work..i think this is alternate solution  ,,,but i'm looking for the best way to do this ,,,,,programetically  @danh

Comment: Why are you trying to mask/add sublayer ? shouldn't you be do something like this : `self.layer.shadowPath = someBezierPath` ?

Comment: without adding/masking View , will i get the ?? i may get the Shadow only  @Gocy015

Comment: @Dhiru ,  so you are using CAShapeLayer to create that little triangle on the top. Adding a mask to a layer will for sure clip its shadow. The workaround maybe adding a superview to hold the entire view ,then add shadow on the superview ,or overriding `drawRect` to draw that triangle instead.

Comment: @danh and  Gocy015 , both have given good suggestions ,,,,i want to just ask , is it impossible to do what i want without any help of other View/ImageView  ??

Comment: @Dhiru http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805872/how-do-i-draw-a-shadow-under-a-uiview

Answer (score -1):

```
extension UIView{

    func viewShadowBorder()  {
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    }
    }
```

Comment: @Dhiru Check if your view background is clear then it will not work.So

Comment: i tried all the things , i think when we mask any View with `CAShaperLayer` we have no longer access to `CALayer` of view .