# Adding clouded shadow to UIView in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

> I want to add shadow(it is not like default it somehow clouded and blurred) for my UIView like below

[image]

I have written an extension as

```
func addShadow(color: UIColor = UIColor.black, opacity: Float = 0.9, radius: CGFloat = 1, scale: Bool = true) {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor

        self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        self.layer.shadowRadius = radius

        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
    }
```

Output:
[image]

but not able to get the exact output.
Your help will be thankful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I draw a shadow under a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805872/how-do-i-draw-a-shadow-under-a-uiview)

Comment: `self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -??)` should do the trick, where -?? is to be tested according to your needs...

Comment: Your `shadowPath` is a rectangle.

Comment: yeah, how I can obtain it as cloudy

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you also need to set `clipsToBounds`.

```
self.clipsToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I use IBInspectable to treat all the views in my app. Try it out

```
extension UIView {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
    }
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
    set {
        layer.borderWidth = newValue
    }
    get {
        return layer.borderWidth
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
    set {
        layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
    }
    get {
        return UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize {
    set {
        layer.shadowOffset = newValue
    }
    get {
        return layer.shadowOffset
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
    set {
        layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
    }
    get {
        return layer.shadowOpacity
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
    set {
        layer.shadowRadius = newValue
    }
    get {
        return layer.shadowRadius
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
    set {
        layer.shadowColor = newValue?.cgColor
    }
    get {
        return UIColor(cgColor: layer.shadowColor!)
    }
}
```

}

in your case you should fix shadowOffset property.

Comment: this way looking awesome to do, but didnt worked with me

Answer (score 0):

You should disable **clipToBounds** in your 'containerView' (view that has your shadow dropping view placed as a subview)

Take a look at an example:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func addShadow(color: UIColor = UIColor.black, opacity: Float = 0.9, radius: CGFloat = 1, scale: Bool = true) {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        self.layer.shadowRadius = radius
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1

    }
}

let shadowedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 100))
shadowedView.backgroundColor = .blue
shadowedView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
shadowedView.addShadow()

let mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height:200))
mainView.backgroundColor = .white
mainView.addSubview(shadowedView)
```

[image]

here I will add a view container and enable clipToBounds :

```
let shadowedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
shadowedView.backgroundColor = .blue
shadowedView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
shadowedView.addShadow()

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 100))
containerView.addSubview(shadowedView)
containerView.clipsToBounds = true

let mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
mainView.backgroundColor = .white
mainView.addSubview(containerView)
```

[image]